# Why command top diplays two processes of redis?

Tags: linux, redis

When I run:

```
[root@ip-10-62-50-27 ~]# ps ef | grep redis
```

I get only one redis running process:

```
25816 pts/1    S+     0:00          \_ grep --color=auto redis XDG_SESSION_ID=c11..
```

However, top command shows that there are two processes:

```
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
25949 redis     20   0 8904472   6.7g   4180 D  87.0 10.7   0:16.84 redis-server
3904 redis     20   0 8904336   6.7g  15616 S   5.6 10.8   1384:19 redis-server
```

Why is that?

Comment: Your `ps ef | grep redis` is showing the `grep` command you ran -- not any running Redis servers. So either (a) you ran that `ps` on a different machine than was running Redis, or (b) who knows what mistake you made.

Comment: [RESOLVED] top command sometimes shows two running redis processes because in the background redis runs BGSAVE in a separate thread. So sometimes there are two threads of redis running (depending on how often BGSAVE command is invoked)

Comment: That doesn't explain why your `ps ef | grep` only shows  the grep command. You must have run that command on a system that was not running Redis. Also, htop doesn't normally display a thread as a distinct process. So I would conclude that the second process was created by your primary Redis server and was not a thread of that process.

Answer (score 0):

[RESOLVED] top command sometimes shows two running redis processes because in the background redis runs BGSAVE in a separate thread. So sometimes there are two threads of redis running (depending on how often BGSAVE command is invoked)